# DOMDocument() xmlns giving "< />" instead of "<>" creating invalid document for google products.

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm attempting to create a valid product feed for google shopping. All is well except this issue here.

DOMDocument() is creating this:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0"/>
```

Whereas the objective is this:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0">
```

Note the missing "/"

I thought < /> was perfectly valid code, but google is rejecting it with this error:

> XML formatting error - Error
>
> Our system encountered an error when processing your data feed. Learn
>   more. Examples: Line Nr. 3    Column Nr. 1

That of course relates to the above tag I mentioned.

The doc starts off this way...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0"/>
<channel>
...
```

I'm not aware there are any issues, yet google says its in error.

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 


$rss = $xml->createElement('rss');
$version = $xml->createAttribute('version');
$rss->appendChild($version);
$value = $xml->createTextNode('2.0');
$version->appendChild($value);


$xmlns_g = $xml->createAttribute('xmlns:g');
$rss->appendChild($xmlns_g);

$value = $xml->createTextNode('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
$xmlns_g->appendChild($value);

$xmlns_c = $xml->createAttribute('xmlns:c');
$rss->appendChild($xmlns_c);

$value = $xml->createTextNode('http://base.google.com/cns/1.0');
$xmlns_c->appendChild($value);

$xml->appendChild($rss);
?>
```

Comment: That code is not where the error is.

Comment: Your answer worked - great job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere further in the code you have something that reads like this:

```
$channel = $xml->createElement('channel');
 ...
$xml->appendChild($channel);
```

**This is incorrect.**

This will add children to the document itself. You must add children to existing nodes, among them the root `rss` node.

```
$channel = $xml->createElement('channel');
 ...
$rss->appendChild($channel);
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. You are pretty skilled to see the exact error in code I never posted!